# Getting "Internal server error" after deploying my WAR file through AppSail service in Zoho Catalyst

Tags: serverless, zoho

I am getting the following error after deploying my WAR file through AppSail service in Zoho Catalyst.

{"status":"failure", "data": {"message": "Internal server error has occurred. Please try again after some time", "error_code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"}}

I have a java WAR file and successfully deployed it to the development environment through the Catalyst CLI. But I am facing the above mentioned error while accessing the development AppSail service URL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Internal Server Error" while using Catalyst AppSail in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77300992/internal-server-error-while-using-catalyst-appsail-in-development)