# "Internal Server Error" while using Catalyst AppSail in development

Tags: catalystbyzoho, catalystserverless, catalystappsail, catalystdevops, catalystlogs

I'm in the process of creating an application with Catalyst AppSail, but I'm encountering an "Internal Server Error." Interestingly, I've confirmed that the application runs smoothly on my local setup. Any ideas on what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you encountered is likely caused by the absence of a Startup command. You can review the [logs](https://docs.catalyst.zoho.com/en/devops/help/logs/introduction/) for your AppSail within the DevOps service section in the Catalyst Console. These logs will assist you in identifying the root of the problem.